Is it possible to build a game with working AssetDatabase?
I making a level editor using AssetDatabase. Every single object saves in individual asset (file). But unfortunately, in Unity we can't build a game with AssetDatabase
(Apart from the fact that scripts with AssetDatabase can be added to the Editor folder, or designated #if UNITY_EDITOR, but it will not work in the assembled game, so this option does not suit me).
Therefore, I ask you for help: maybe there is something similar to AssetDatabase with which you can build the game, or are there any tools in the Unity Asset Store
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
using DG.Tweening;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Level Object", menuName = "Level Object")]
public class ObjectProperty : ScriptableObject
{
    [Header("Main")]
    public string objectName;
    public string shape = "Ball";
    public Vector2 position = Vector2.zero;
    public float rotation = 0;
    public int sortingOrder;
    public Color color = Color.white;
    public float opacity = 1f;
    public bool glow = false;
    public float glowIntensity = .2f;
    public float glowRadius = 1f;
    public float glowSmoothness = .5f;

    [Header("Extended")]
    public float spawnDelay = 0f;
    public float movingSpeed = 5f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    public Ease easing = Ease.InOutCubic;

    public static int number = 1;
    public static string assetPath = "Assets/Scripts/LevelEditor/Object/ObjectSaving/LevelTest";

    public static GameObject CreateObjectByAsset(ObjectProperty data) // Reads asset file at the given path and spawns the GameObject from the file data
    {
        GameObject spawnedObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>($"Objects/EditorPrefabs/{data.shape}"), data.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, data.rotation));
        SpriteRenderer renderer = spawnedObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        Light2D glow = spawnedObject.GetComponent<Light2D>();

        spawnedObject.name = data.objectName;

        renderer.color = new(data.color.r, data.color.g, data.color.b, data.opacity);
        renderer.sortingOrder = data.sortingOrder;

        glow.enabled = data.glow;
        glow.color = renderer.color;
        glow.intensity = data.glowIntensity;
        glow.pointLightOuterRadius = data.glowRadius;
        glow.falloffIntensity = data.glowSmoothness;

        return spawnedObject;
    }
    public static ObjectProperty SaveGameObjectInAsset(GameObject obj) // Saves the GameObject to an asset file with return ability
    {
        SpriteRenderer renderer = obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        Light2D glow = obj.GetComponent<Light2D>();

        if (Directory.GetFiles(assetPath).Length == 0)
            number = 1;

        while (File.Exists($"{assetPath}/{number}.asset"))
            number++;

        ObjectProperty data = CreateInstance<ObjectProperty>();
            data.objectName = obj.name;
            data.shape = renderer.sprite.name;
            data.position = obj.transform.position;
            data.rotation = obj.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
            data.sortingOrder = renderer.sortingOrder;
            data.color = new(renderer.color.r, renderer.color.g, renderer.color.b);
            data.opacity = renderer.color.a;
            data.glow = glow.enabled;
            data.glowIntensity = glow.intensity;
            data.glowRadius = glow.pointLightOuterRadius;
            data.glowSmoothness = glow.falloffIntensity;

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(data, $"{assetPath}/{number}.asset");
        ObjectProperty asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<ObjectProperty>($"{assetPath}/{number}.asset");

        return asset;
    }
    public static ObjectProperty FindAssetByNumber(int number) // Finds an asset file by number: Obj1, Obj2, Obj3...
    {
        ObjectProperty data = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<ObjectProperty>($"{assetPath}/{number}.asset");
        return data;
    }
    public static ObjectProperty[] GetObjectProperties()
    {
        string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets($"t:{nameof(ObjectProperty)}", new[] {ObjectProperty.assetPath});
        ObjectProperty[] datas = new ObjectProperty[guids.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
        {
            string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guids[i]);
            datas[i] = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<ObjectProperty>(assetPath);
        }

        return datas;
    }
    public static void DeleteAsset(int number) // Finds an ObjectProperty asset and deletes it
    {
        AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset($"{assetPath}/{number}.asset");
    }

    public static void ClearAllAssets() // Clears all the assets in the ObjectProperty assets directory and resets the number
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(assetPath);

        foreach (string file in files)
            File.Delete(file);

        number = 1; 
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("number", number);
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public static void SaveAssets() =>
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
}

I have already tried saving files with JSON 3 times, but without success - it turned out to be too difficult for me.
When building a game I get errors that "The name 'AssetDatabase' does not exist in the current context"

well 99.9% of your folderstructure will never be in your end game as that structure.   Your choices are, resources, streaming assets and unitys user defined content

You can't use AssetDatabase or any other entities, placed inside UnityEditor namespace. The closest to AssetDatabase features, that you can use, I believe, is Resources.
Also you can check Streaming Assets, it could be used with just regular file system on most platforms. But there are some hidden difficulties you can face on some platforms, like Android.
And more advanced(but also more difficult) way to manage your asses is Addressables. But I recommend you not migrate to Addressables, without understanding of how it works and why you need it.
